# Не показывает время получения уведомления

Tags: android, android-notification

Мой notification:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT,str2);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// оставим только самое необходимое
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ico)
                .setContentTitle("Hodite")
                .setContentText(str1); // Текст уведомления

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
// ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify((str1+str2).hashCode(),notification);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрев на скрин вы заметите,что не показывает время получения уведомления.

На других версиях может показывать.

Что я упустил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите время явно через`NotificationCompat.Builder#setWhen(long time)`:

```
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ico)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentTitle("Hodite")
        .setContentText(str1);
```